# How can I create Server-side events from an EventStream in Akka?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I tried: EventStream -> Source -> Akka HTTP (SSE)

As I see it, this cannot work, because the source will be materialized by Akka HTTP `complete(Source, ...)`
and to send messages from the EventStream to the materialized Source I need the ActorRef (is there a way to get that ActorRef?)

---

I've found a solution on GitHub which uses ActorPublisher:
https://github.com/calvinlfer/Akka-HTTP-Akka-Streams-Akka-Actors-Integration

But since ActorPublisher is an internal API, I am still hoping for clean solution.

Comment: How would the developer know when the stream of events from `EventStream` is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Source.actorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#actorRef[T](bufferSize:Int,overflowStrategy:akka.stream.OverflowStrategy):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.actor.ActorRef]) to create a `Source` that converts event stream elements to [`ServerSentEvent`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/sse/ServerSentEvent.html) instances, and [`BroadcastHub.sink`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/BroadcastHub$.html#sink[T]:akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[T,akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]]), in a manner like the following:

```scala
val (sseActor, sseSource) =
  Source.actorRef[EventStreamMessageOrWhatever](10, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
    .map(s => /* convert event stream elements to ServerSideEvent */)
    .keepAlive(1.second, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
    .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[ServerSentEvent])(Keep.both)
    .run()
```

If there is downstream demand, messages (i.e., event stream elements) sent to the materialized `ActorRef` are emitted downstream. If there is no downstream demand, the messages are buffered up to a certain number (in this example, the buffer size is 10) with the specified overflow strategy.

You can then subscribe the materialized actor to the `EventStream`:

```scala
eventStream.subscribe(sseActor, ...)
```

And the materialized `Source` is available for use in your path:

```scala
path("sse") {
  get {
    complete(sseSource)
  }
}
```

Note that there is no backpressure with this approach.